# Problem with getting results with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup, automation, html-parsing

I am learning about web parsing and i created a python script using BS4.
when i try to run this script, i am only getting input for 1 item.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = 'https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-sydney/computer/k0l3003435?price-type=free'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0)'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.content
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')
items_list = soup.find_all('section', {'class': 'search-results-page__user-ad-collection'})
for items in items_list:
    title = items.find('span', {'class': 'user-ad-row-new-design__title-span'}).text
    url_tag = items.find('a', {'href': 'user-ad-row-new-design.link--base-color-inherit.link--hover-color-none.link--no-underline'})
    url = url_tag.text if url_tag else "n/a"
print('item:', title, '\nlink:', url)
```

For some reason i am getting result for only one item?

```
item: PC Joysticks 
link: n/a
```

can any one please help me out.

**Note:** This is my first time posting here so apologies in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: your parent root `'section', {'class': 'search-results-page__user-ad-collection'})`, which on the you are requesting is only one item -> thats why you only print one tuple of `(title, url)`

Instead you can find the list of `<div>`s that correspond to each ad, and then search for title and url for each of them.

Here are the changes I made that works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


url = 'https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-sydney/computer/k0l3003435?price-type=free'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0)'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# response.content
# print(response.content)
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')
# items_list = soup.find_all('section', {'class': 'search-results-page__user-ad-collection'})
items_list = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'user-ad-row-new-design link link--base-color-inherit link--hover-color-none link--no-underline'}, href=True)
for items in items_list:
    title = items.find('span', {'class': 'user-ad-row-new-design__title-span'}).text
    url = items['href']
    print('item:', title, '\nlink:', url)
```

Output:

```
item: Computer chair 
link: /s-ad/minchinbury/office-chairs/computer-chair/1260894371
item: Free computer table workstation 
link: /s-ad/haberfield/desks/free-computer-table-workstation/1260881353
item: PC Joysticks 
link: /s-ad/old-toongabbie/computer-accessories/pc-joysticks/1260849652
item: computer desk 
link: /s-ad/menai/desks/computer-desk/1260826750
item:  ONLINE  Tutor in Maths, Science and Engineering ASSIGNMENT 
link: /s-ad/the-rocks/other-books-music-games/-online-tutor-in-maths-science-and-engineering-assignment/1260785917
item: Childrens' soft toys, family board games, assorted art, clothes 
link: /s-ad/avalon/toys-indoor/childrens-soft-toys-family-board-games-assorted-art-clothes/1260750520
item: Free computer chair. 
link: /s-ad/liverpool/computer-accessories/free-computer-chair-/1260749656
item: Wanted Free DEAD OR ALIVE Computers all types for personal training. 
link: /s-ad/north-richmond/other-electronics-computers/wanted-free-dead-or-alive-computers-all-types-for-personal-training-/1260659962
item: DVI-D Video Cable 
link: /s-ad/stanmore/computer-accessories/dvi-d-video-cable/1260657663
item: Computer games and controller 
link: /s-ad/kensington/video-games/computer-games-and-controller/1260568719
item: Two garage sales, Some of them FREE to go 
link: /s-ad/eastwood/sofas/two-garage-sales-some-of-them-free-to-go/1260562401
item: Antec case free 
link: /s-ad/ermington/components/antec-case-free/1260451058
item: Free computer chair 
link: /s-ad/caringbah/office-chairs/free-computer-chair/1260411306
item: Computer tables 
link: /s-ad/werrington/other-electronics-computers/computer-tables/1260373820
item: Large desk 750cms depth, 150cms wide, 74cms high, two drawers, beige 
link: /s-ad/marrickville/desks/large-desk-750cms-depth-150cms-wide-74cms-high-two-drawers-beige/1260365079
item: Computer books 
link: /s-ad/belmore/textbooks/computer-books/1260345045
item: Windows XP computer games 
link: /s-ad/east-kurrajong/software/windows-xp-computer-games/1260332226
item: Computer office chair 
link: /s-ad/fairfield/office-chairs/computer-office-chair/1260286224
item: i want non working/ old computers 
link: /s-ad/sydney-region/desktops/i-want-non-working-old-computers/1260194032
item: accountant books 
link: /s-ad/epping/other-books-music-games/accountant-books/1260156161
item: FREE    FREE - SAVE FROM LANDFILL - Office cabinet -has slight damage 
link: /s-ad/wetherill-park/cabinets/free-free-save-from-landfill-office-cabinet-has-slight-damage/1259887356
item: Desktop computer desk 
link: /s-ad/miranda/desks/desktop-computer-desk/1259807032
item: Harwood desk, computer table or study desk 
link: /s-ad/rosebery/desks/harwood-desk-computer-table-or-study-desk/1259782448
item: HP Deskjet D2360 Free 
link: /s-ad/neutral-bay/printers-scanners/hp-deskjet-d2360-free/1259631311
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with indentation.
Push your last print line within the for loop:

```
for items in items_list:
    title = items.find('span', {'class': 'user-ad-row-new-design__title-span'}).text
    url_tag = items.find('a', {'href': 'user-ad-row-new-design.link--base-color-inherit.link--hover-color-none.link--no-underline'})
    url = url_tag.text if url_tag else "n/a"
    print('item:', title, '\nlink:', url)
```

Comment: Hi Serial, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion and its still giving me same results.

Comment: @JagjotSingh there were a couple of problems in your code the way you were fetching the parent element. I've added a new answer that returns the expected response, check that out

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? I have not beautified the ouput

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = 'https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-sydney/computer/k0l3003435?price-type=free'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0)'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BS(response.content, 'html.parser')
items_list = soup.find_all('section', {'class': 'search-results-page__user-ad-collection'})
for item in items_list:
    print(item.text)
for item in items_list:
    url_tag = item.find('a', {'href': 'user-ad-row-new-design.link--base-color-inherit.link--hover-color-none.link--no-underline'})
    url = url_tag.text if url_tag else "n/a"
    print('item:\n', item.text, '\nlink:', url)
```

Output:-

```
Dell latitude 5510 laptop computerI am selling my laptop for $275. If you buy it, another identical laptop is FREE. Dual boot. Both computers have Windows 7 Professional and Windows 10 Pro, and you can choose the one you want to run. Intel Core i5 520M CPU (2.4GHz, 3M cache) (Dual Core) 4GB RAM 15.6” HD Anti-Glare LED Display DVD-ROM, DVD-RW, CD/DVD writer/recorder AC Adapter (fast charging technology) 4-cell battery 64 bit 4 usb ports 160 GB harddisk Office 2010 No webcam Windows 7 is activated with genuine key. IFreePrestons, NSW2 hours agoPC JoysticksHave two sets of old computer joysticks and throttles. These will require a "USB to game port" adapter to be purchased to work. Here is a suggested link to check (https://www.sbtech.com.au/usb-to-game-port-adaptor/) 
No guarantees that they work at all and as such they are offered as a lot for free. 
For pickup from Constitution Hill (near Parramatta NSW).FreeOld Toongabbie, NSW4 hours agoFree metal desk computer workstationFree desk about 2.5metres long. Pick up from FivedockFreeHaberfield, NSW4 hours agocomputer deskUsed computer desk with chair in reasonable condition. 
Desk is a little bowed and chair a little knocked about but still perfectly fine. 
Pick up only from Sutherland Shire areaFreeMenai, NSW7 hours ago ONLINE  Tutor in Maths, Science and Engineering ASSIGNMENTOnline Tutor in Accounting, Algebra, Anatomy, Biochemistry, Biology, Business Studies, Calculus, Chemistry, Computing, Economics, Engineer, Engineering, Essay Writing, Finance, Further Maths, General Science, Geometry, Health Studies, Human Biology, Management, Maths, Maths Methods, Microbiology, Microsoft Office, Nutrition, Physical Education, Physics, Physiology, Programming, Statistics, UMAT. 
Whether you need to catch up with class, have difficulty with exams looming or just want the extrFreeThe Rocks, NSW21 hours agoChildrens' soft toys, family board games, assorted art, clothesA collection of soft toys (all clean) and family board games, free 
Framed art and prints, canvas botanical prints, free...
```